How can I structure a certain dynamic view?
I've looked at drupal/views_taxonomy_term_name_depth and contextual filters in views, and that works somewhat, but I have the following request/example.
Let's say I have Content Types: City, Article, and I also have a Tag hierarchy:
Tags:

Chicago
  - Sushi Restaurants
  - Museums
Atlanta
  - Parks
  - Museums

And I'd like to display, on a city page, the specific header (eg Sushi Restaurants) for a view, and all the articles tagged Sushi Restaurants. Alternatively, I can have this tag structure:
Tags:

Chicago
  - featured_tag_one
  - featured_tag_two
Atlanta
  - featured_tag_one
  - featured_tag_two

And tag articles as belonging to one city or another, first feature set or the second. However, each feature set would still have to have a title (e.g. Sushi Restaurants) and any number of fields.
How would I structure this? I'm hoping to NOT create a page for each city, and rather use something like contextual filters.
